# What does it mean to say that a list is locked internally?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, collections, effective-java

This code is from the book Effective Java

```
Object[] snapshot = list.toArray();// Locks list internally
```

I am mainly interested in the comment here .  Does it make the list `unmodifiable` ? What does it mean to say that a list is locked internally ? How long is this lock kept ? Is there a better alternative to convert a List to an array ?

Comment: its about thread safety

Comment: can you post more context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that it means the list doesn't maintain a reference to the returned array, meaning that the array can be modified without affecting the original list from where it came. Likewise, any modifications to the list won't be reflected in the array.

This is important in terms of thread safety, because it means you can iterate on the contents of the list from a thread-safe perspective, without worrying about another thread altering the sttae of the list in the meantime. In this sense the state of the list is "locked" in the returned array, no matter what changes are made to the list afterwards - you can see it as taking a snapshot.

`toArray();` doesn't alter the state of the list - so it doesn't make it unmodifiable or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others said, I think that is about concurrency:

Text from javadoc of java.uitl.List

> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are
>       maintained by this list.  (In other words, this method must
>       allocate a new array even if this list is backed by an array).
>       The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

Its about thread safety - i.e. **conversion of the list to Array will be thread safe**

**Edit:**
In simplest way - you can take it as

- when `Thread one` is converting **List -> Array** no other thread is allowed to alter the list till the time `Thread one` has not completed the conversion

Comment: Can you give a reference to this?  Looking at the source of ArrayList.toArray(), I don't see any locks that would prevent another thread from modifying the state of the ArrayList while toArray is in process.

Comment: Your bullet is not technically correct.  All that occurs is a System.arraycopy.  So 1 thread can enter the `toArray` method and, before invocation of System.arraycopy, another thread can modify the list.  The 'lock' is more correctly explained by berry120 in which it locks the current state in place and assigns to a new array.

Comment: @sharakan @-john yeah m diving into the source code to look in depth - though  agree @-berry is correct

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering where the "internal locking" takes place:

Please note that J. Bloch writes as an introduction for the given code: *"For example, suppose you have a **synchronized** list (of the sort returned by `Collections.synchroniedList`) (...)"*

In that case `toArray()` really "locks internal" because the implementation of the synchronized list will do just that (with a mutex) preventing any modification by other threads while the decoupled array is created.